# Web2py problems with SQLFORM Translation

Tags: javascript, python, model-view-controller, web2py

hi guys so my problem is this in Pt_br language there is many ç´^ and other acentuations, i have a sqlform that has
    `Tipo de Servico` but i need to present on html with the proper letter -> `Tipo de Serviço` since im letting the sqlform create the html for me there is a way to add the ç only in the html? i tried entering the default language file and add a translation there to that string but it doenst change
    `'Tipo de Servico': 'Tipo de Serviço'` is there any way like to change that? via js maybe?

controller default.py:

```
def pedido():
    pedido = SQLFORM(db.pedido)
return dict(pedido=pedido)
```

db.py:

```
db.define_table('pedido',
    Field('Tipo_de_servico', 'string'))
```

view:

```
extend of my layout and {{=pedido}}
```

on my html `Tipo De Servico` <- i only need to change this to `Tipo de Serviço`.

on a 2 matter when i submit my form is there a way that i can make the user input either his user ou pass to validate? assuming the user is logged, this will restric other users to submit if the user forget to logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, web2py creates labels for fields based on the field name (it replaces underscores with spaces and converts to title case). However, it does not pass labels created in this way through the translator, so adding a translation will have no effect.

Instead, you can explicitly provide a label for the field:

```
Field('Tipo_de_servico', 'string', label='Tipo de Serviço')
```

If desired, you can even provide translations for such labels by wrapping them in `T()`:

```
Field('Tipo_de_servico', 'string', label=T('Tipo de Serviço'))
```

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer so others know it works.